# svn: /etc/subversion/servers:6: Section header expected

Tags: svn, unix, proxy

I have to add proxy in the `/etc/subversion/servers` file.

```
  http-proxy-host=web-proxy.xxx.xxx.com
  http-proxy-port=8080
```

After adding the proxy info I am getting the above error while executing the `svn` command. 
Now the error message clearly indicates line number 6 which is the proxy host. If I comment that line then svn commands starts working.

Now after googling several forums I found that I have to put the info `"under [global] section and not at file's head"`

- So where is the [global] section in unix file system ? Is it the `config` file ?
- Is there any other way to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[global]
http-proxy-host=web-proxy.xxx.xxx.com
http-proxy-port=8080
```

Comment: Whoops ! Now this is silly :) I was trying the same in config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the below to the `subversion/servers` file by finding the `[global]` value in it and adding your configuration immediately below it:

```
[global]
http-proxy-host=YOUR_web-proxy.xxx.xxx.com
http-proxy-port=YOUR_PORT
http-proxy-username=YOUR_USERNAME
http-proxy-password=YOUR_PASSWORD
```

**PS:** For `Windows` users, you can find the `servers` file at `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Subversion`